# I have a query that returns multiple rows and i want to display them 1 row every 5 seconds

Tags: php

I have a query that returns (x) rows. I want to display those rows in a div. 
I want to display the data 1 row at a time cycling through them every 5 seconds.
Each row contain 2 sections, if the second section is blank I need to display the first section if not I need to display the second section.

I have the code to run the query and to display the information but im struggling to find out how to display 1 row at a time for a few seconds then show the next row looping till the end.

This is the code I have to check for the right part of the data to display and then display only the relevant part of the data but it returns all rows in one go.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
Echo "</br>";
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
Echo "</br>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if ($row['H2']<>"103"){
$WLcombined = "103_". $row['name']."_of_".$row['CName']."_hit_".$row['AName'];
} 
else
{
$WLcombined = "103_". $row['name']."_of_".$row['CName']."_hit_".$row['A1Name'];
}


Echo ($WLcombined. "</br>") ;  

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Most common practice is use of jquery/ajax. Give a try with jquery then let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is referred to as a "ticker". This is not possible using php alone. You will require client side javascript to scroll the results as you have described. [This page](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/490/top-5-best-javascript-and-jquery-marquee-news-ticker-plugins) lists several freely available ticker plugins.

Comment: JQuery worked perfectly for me thank you.  I ended up going with a really simple ticker. Trying to put the data in dynamically was difficult with many of them. I ended up using this one as it was each to dump the php and MySqli in the middl to create the list [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Mobile-friendly-News-Ticker-with-jQuery-CSS3-Responsive-Ticker.html)

Answer (score -2):

you should try output buffering (http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

```
ob_start();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['H2'] <> "103") {
        $WLcombined = "103_".$row['name']."_of_".$row['CName']."_hit_".$row['AName'];
    } else {
        $WLcombined = "103_".$row['name']."_of_".$row['CName']."_hit_".$row['A1Name'];
    }


    Echo($WLcombined."</br>");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
}
```

I would not recommend doing this from PHP, JavaScript is more suited for this.

Comment: I added this, now the page fails to load and I end up with a connection timed out error.